# DataSnap VCL App server hangs if it is closed with open connections

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7, indy10, datasnap

as the subject says, just close a DS App with 1 open connection and it hangs.

The issue is related to procedure TIdScheduler.TerminateAllYarns;because it get into an infinite loop trying to close all yarns.

The issue is similar to this reported by another user.

http://www.codenewsfast.com/cnf/article/0/permalink.art-ng2026q2000

Regards,

Comment: Such a hang would happen on mobile platforms due to ARC. `TIdSchedulerOfThread.TerminateYarn()` would fail to terminate the thread because `FreeAndNil(LYarn)` was not destroying the yarn (thus not destroying the thread) on mobile platforms because other ARC references to the yarn object were keeping its reference count above 0. That was fixed last year when `IdDisposeAndNil()` was added to Indy.

Comment: Im not working con mobile plarform but I think it could be the same issue. How can I fix it? Ideas? Thanks

Comment: Embarcadero uses a private copy of Indy for DataSnap. You cannot recompile DataSnap itself, but you should be able to recompile Embarcadero's **IndyPeerImpl** package, which DataSnap uses as a bridge to Indy (read Indy's [installation notes](http://www.indyproject.org/sockets/Docs/Indy10Installation.aspx) about that).  That should allow you to upgrade to a newer Indy version and have DataSnap utilize it.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem for me too. I've implemented a DataSnap CallBack example in Delphi XE3 and Delphi 10 Seattle: both hangs if one or more client are connected to the server.
But they hangs only when I close directly the server Windows application.
Try calling before:

```
ServerContainer1.DSServer1.Stop;
```

It works for me.